# HP Laserjet 1300n standalone drivers for Win7 64bit, copy from windows update

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-update, network-printer

I've just got a new laptop with Windows 7 64bit. I share my printers out from a CUPS server and under Windows XP it was easy to connect to my shared printers. I would just navigate to \\server and all my printers would be listed, then right click on the desired one and click "Connect" then click the have disk option to point it to the network folder containing the drivers for that printer. I realise I could load the drivers on my CUPS server and have them automatically downloaded by the printer but when I originally setup CUPS it looked like alot more effort to do that so I never bothered.

I'm having some trouble getting the printer drivers under Windows 7.
The printer in question is an HP Laserjet 1300n which is old but still works perfectly. I was digging around the HP site and the only drivers they seem to offer is a universal print driver which is horrible. I can't find a standalone driver anywhere.

If I try and add a printer from Control Panel > Devices and Printers, I've found I can click the "Windows Update" button and extra printers are listed under the HP section, and the Laserjet 1300 PCL5 is one of them. So it seems a standalone driver is available through Windows Update.

But when I try right clicking the printer under \\server and clicking "Connect", I get the manufacturer/model browse screen but without a "Windows Update" button. So that's a strange UI inconsistency there.

I've got round this problem by installing a fake local copy of my printer attached to LPT1 and using the "Windows Update" button to give me access to extra print drivers. Then removing it. And then the driver is listed when I do the \\server "Connect" method as I guess the driver's already been downloaded from Windows Update and is cached.

So I'm just wondering... is there a way I can access this standalone print driver that's been downloaded from Windows Update and copy it to a folder so I can just go "Have Disk" in the future?

Cheers, B

Comment: Which computer is sharing the printer? XP or Windows 7, and what are the versions? 32- or 64-bit for each printer connecting?

Comment: The computer sharing the printer is my Linux home server running CentOS 5.6, Samba and CUPS. I'm trying to get the standalone drivers for Windows 7 64bit to be able to connect to a printer on my Linux samba server.

Comment: Sorry, I would love to help, but I am really a Microsoft guy. I could have told you how to do it pretty much any Windows system to Windows system. Good luck.